# How to print an index of element in a list - python

Tags: python, loops, indexing

#Program that will load 2 arrays. ELements of the first array are coordinates X. and#the elements of the second array are coordinates Y of a point on a plane.# find the point and print the index of coordinates of the point which is the closest to the#starting point, coordinate 0,0.

```
import math

i = 0
X = [3,32,15,43,5,22,90,1]
Y = [3,32,15,43,5,22,90,1]
min = math.sqrt(X[0])**2 + math.sqrt(Y[0])**2
while i < len(X):
    U = math.sqrt(X[i])**2 + math.sqrt(Y[i])**2
    if U < min:
        min = U
    else:
        min = min
    i = i + 1

mindex = X.index(min)


print(min)
print(mindex)
```

so basically the coordinates should be 1,1 since that is the shortest distance from the nul-point with the distance D = 2.But how do I also print the index of that element 1. With the index being 7

Edit: in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
import math

X = [3, 32, 15, 43, 5, 22, 90, 1]
Y = [3, 32, 15, 43, 5, 22, 90, 1]

# calculate distances using list comprehension
distances = [math.sqrt(x) ** 2 + math.sqrt(y) ** 2 for x, y in zip(X, Y)]

# find minimal distance
min_distance = min(distances)

# find index of minimal index
min_distance_index = distances.index(min_distance)
print(min_distance, min_distance_index)  # Output: 2.0 7
```

Comment: Thank you. this was very useful. I've started coding about a week ago and people like you make it a lot more fun. I didn't even know about "zip"

Answer (score 0):

Just a heads up, you got the wrong formula for euclidean distance. Your formula comes down to `x + y` if they're both positive, otherwise you get an error. The actual formula is `math.sqrt(x ** 2 + y ** 2)`

From the phrasing of your question it sounds like you only want to print the index, in which case the following is enough

```
import math

X = [3,32,15,43,5,22,90,1]
Y = [3,32,15,43,5,22,90,1]

min_index = min(range(len(X)), key=lambda i: math.sqrt(X[i] ** 2 + Y[i] ** 2))
print(min_index)
```

Comment: They say point (1, 1) has distance 2. You compute sqrt(2) instead.

Comment: Who says that? What measure of distance do you need to use?

Comment: The OP says that. In the question.

Comment: Oh sorry I had you confused with the OP there. I gathered that that was simply the result of running the code, not part of the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Super easy, barely an inconvenience.

```
>>> min(range(len(X)), key=lambda i: X[i] + Y[i])
7
```

(No idea what you think squaring square roots achieves, so I removed that.)

Answer (score -1):

check this:

```
import math

i = 0
X = [3,32,15,43,5,22,90,1]
Y = [3,32,15,43,5,22,90,1]
min = math.sqrt(X[0])**2 + math.sqrt(Y[0])**2
idx = 0
while i < len(X):
    U = math.sqrt(X[i])**2 + math.sqrt(Y[i])**2
    if U < min:
        min = U
        idx = i
    i = i + 1

print(min)
print(idx)
```

Comment: Just i misspelled idx as index now it is correted

Comment: but that will loop until through the whole list so the variable i will always be equal to the number of elements inside the list, so i will always be equal to 7, even if I change the elements in the list.

Comment: No required index will be stored in variable `idx` it only updates when new distance is less than previous minimum. Change the elements and check

Comment: Okay but that doesn't help me either since unless every next distance is larger than the last it won't actually track indexes.
[10,9,5,10,3,8,1]
the shortest distance in this case is number 1 with the index 6, 
but by your logic the index would be 3